# Почему sublime text ругается на return

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

*Sublime Text 3* ругается на `return` (выделил заглавными буквами).
Это *Telegram* бот. Я создал вторую кнопку, и почему-то `return` выделяется ошибкой, не могу понять почему.

Вот сам код:

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram import KeyboardButton
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardRemove
from telegram.ext import CallbackContext
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import Filters
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler

button_help = 'Выплата'
button_reg = 'Регистрация'

def button_help_handler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    update.message.reply_text(
        text='Чтобы заказать выплату надо...',
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),

        )

def button_reg_handler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    update.message.reply_text(
        text='Чтобы зарегистрироваться надо...',
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),
            ***RETURN(ругается на этот) button_reg_handler(update=update, context=context)***
        

def message_handler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    text = update.message.text
    if text == button_help:
        return button_help_handler(update=update, context=context)


    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        keyboard=[
            [
                KeyboardButton(text=button_reg),
                 KeyboardButton(text=button_help),
            ],

        ],
        resize_keyboard=True,
    )   


    update.message.reply_text(
        text='Нажми кнопку помощь',
        reply_markup=reply_markup,
        )


def main():
    print('start')

    updater = Updater(
        token='1607912298:AAE******************gLBlFUCB-pelM5w_qU',
        use_context=True,
        )

    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters=Filters.all, callback= message_handler))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def button_reg_handler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    update.message.reply_text(
        text='Чтобы зарегистрироваться надо...',
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    return button_reg_handler(update=update, context=context)
```

В следующей строке был закрыт список аргументов:

```
    reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
```

После нее была приведена в порядок табуляция перед `return`.

---

`Sublime text` просто подсвечивал синтаксическую ошибку: ключевое слово `return` внутри списка аргументов функции.

Comment: Спасибо, завтра попробую